# Using MySQL random row in a select statement afterwards

Tags: php, mysql, random, comparison, row

I have a data base 'School'. It has only one table - 'Words'. There are word_id, word_name, word_description in it. I want to pull a random description and display it on a page. Then I want to input a word and see if the word has the same description as the random one that was pulled. What am I doing wrong? Here is the code -

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Изпит</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'school');
        if(!$connection){
            echo 'NOT OK';
            exit;
        }

        if(isset($_POST['submit_description'])){
            $q = mysqli_query($connection, ' SELECT word_description
FROM words ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
');
        $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($q);
                if($row){
                    $_POST['word_description'] = $row['word_description'];
                    echo $_POST['word_description'];
                }

        }

            if(isset($_POST['submit_word'])){
            $word_name = $_POST['word_name'];
            $q2="SELECT * FROM words WHERE word_name='$word_name' and word_description='".$_POST['word_decsription']."'";
            $result=mysqli_query($connection, $q2);
            $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

            if($count==1){
                echo 'Позна ве.';
            }else{
                echo 'Не позна ве.';
            }

        }
        ?>
        <br><br><br>
        <form method="POST">
            <input type="submit" name="submit_description" value="Искай описание.">         
            <input type="hidden" name="word_description" value="<?php echo $_POST['word_description']?>">
        </form> 

        <form method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="word_name">
            <input type="submit" name="submit_word" value="Провери дума.">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.  Also `or die(mysqli_error($connection))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: `word_decsription` != `word_description`

Comment: ^^^ Good catch, one that error reporting and checking on the DB side would have caught, IF the OP were using it.

Comment: I know this isn't helping you in any shape and form with what you asked but try use PDO instead of MySQLi. You will benefit in the long term and it is a lot easier to work with!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some typos.

This line of code here:

```
 $q2="SELECT * FROM words WHERE word_name='$word_name' and word_description='".$_POST['word_decsription']."'";
```

Should be like this:

```
 $q2="SELECT * FROM words WHERE word_name='".$word_name."' and word_description='".$_POST['word_description']."'";
```

Comment: There's no syntax errors, least not in what you're comparing with.

Comment: You're correct, I termed it incorrectly. I still think he's trying to find $word_name variable from the words table and not the word '$word_name'

Comment: Seems more like a typo. See the comment under OP's question.

Comment: So how can I check if the word_name equals it's description in the data base? Please tell if you are not understanding me I will explain it better.

Comment: @Генчев.СтоянГенчев Are you not reading the comments under your question?

Comment: @Генчев.СтоянГенчев I think I understand the intent. You want to pull a random description and display it on a page. Then you want to input a word and see if the word has the same description as the random one that was pulled?

Comment: Yeeees. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

1) There is a typo in $_POST['word_description'] in your query:

```
$q2="SELECT * FROM words WHERE word_name='$word_name' and word_description='".$_POST['word_decsription']."'";
```

2) Also, I would recommend using the word_id instead of the word description to make the verification... you would need to write it in a `<input name="word_id" type="hidden" value="..." />` in your form to pass it along.
What would be even better, to prevent people from knowing the answer by looking at the code (in case they would know what word matches what id), you could encode the value in the hidden field to be `md5($word_id.$word_name)` and then in your query you check `"WHERE MD5(CONCAT(word_id, word_name))='".$_POST['word_md5']."'"` (assuming your hidden input is now called "word_md5).

EDIT:
After looking at the HTML I see what your problem is:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="submit_description" value="Искай описание.">         
    <input type="hidden" name="word_description" value="<?php echo $_POST['word_description']?>">
</form> 

<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="word_name">
    <input type="submit" name="submit_word" value="Провери дума.">
</form>
```

This should all be in the same `<form>` element:

```
<form method="POST">     
    The word description is: <?php echo $_POST['word_description']; ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="word_description" value="<?php echo $_POST['word_description']?>">
    <input type="text" name="word_name">
    <input type="submit" name="submit_word" value="Провери дума.">
</form>
```

When the form is submitted, the $_POST array should contain the word_description AND the word_name submitted.

EDIT 2:
If you wish to use the id, you would have to first add it to your SELECT query:

```
$q = mysqli_query($connection, ' SELECT word_id, word_description
FROM words ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
');
```

Then you'd need to set it to some variable, and then later in your HTML:

```
<form method="POST">     
    The word description is: <?php echo $_POST['word_description']; ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="word_id" value="<?php echo $word_id?>">
    <input type="text" name="word_name">
    <input type="submit" name="submit_word" value="Провери дума.">
</form>
```

Your second SQL query should then look like:

```
$q2="SELECT * FROM words WHERE word_name='$word_name' and word_id='".$_POST['word_id']."'";
```

Note: it is a bad practice to change the $_POST array in your code.

This array is populated by the request sent by the client and things can get confusing if you change the values there.
It is better to create another variable and set it to the value from the $_POST (example: `$word_description = $_POST['word_description'];`).

This way, you can still use `array_key_exists('word_description', $_POST)` to verify if the client actually sent something.

Comment: Okay I feel dump like hell now. I am new to PHP and programming and there is really no one I can ask. All I want is to see if I have learnt my english words for the exam tomorrow. Getting random description and writing down the word. If it's correct, great, if not..will see. Always when I type a word name it says it's not the one the description follows. I don't know how to make it with the word_id stuff. I didn't even know there is an input with a hidden type... Can you show me how to do it?